# Same mesh graduations on a plane as axes ticks

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, output-formatting, grid-lines

I need to define a plane with a mesh as a reference plane.  Currently, the mesh lines don't match the axes ticks.  That plane is defined so it can adapt automatically to a variable scale in a `Manipulate` box (the `Xmax` parameter below).

Is there a way to make the mesh lines to automatically get the same spacing as the axes ticks ?

Here's an example showing the problem :  the mesh grid doesn't match the axes ticks :

```
Xmax = 10;

plane  = ParametricPlot3D[
    {x, y, 0},
    {x, -Xmax, Xmax},
    {y, -Xmax, Xmax},
    Mesh -> Automatic,
    MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.85],
    PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1]},
    BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray],
    PlotRange -> {{-Xmax, Xmax}, {-Xmax, Xmax}, {-Xmax, Xmax}},
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    Ticks -> True,
    Lighting -> "Neutral"
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:

I think I was trying to be too clever in my previous approach: `FindDivisions` seems to do everything we need in such a symmetric case without any hand-holding, simply by specifying that we search for "about 20 divisions":

```
Xmax = 10;

ParametricPlot3D[
  {x, y, 0}, {x, -Xmax, Xmax}, {y, -Xmax, Xmax},

  (* THIS IS THE CHANGE TO YOUR CODE *)
   Mesh -> {FindDivisions[{-Xmax, Xmax}, 20]},

  MeshStyle -> GrayLevel[0.85], PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1]}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thin, Gray], 
  PlotRange -> {{-Xmax, Xmax}, {-Xmax, Xmax}, {-Xmax, Xmax}}, 
  Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> True, 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"
]
```

This works out of the box for `Xmax = 10, 1, 0.6, 0.1, 0.001`. For instance, for the case that failed before:

```
Xmax = 0.6;
```

[image: new plot]

Here are a few more examples for `{Xmax, PowerRange[0.001, 100, 10]}`:

[image: multiple plots]

Comment: BTW, at least in v9 `AbsoluteOptions[ plot, Ticks]` doesn't return the ticks.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Yep, `AbsoluteOptions` is still horribly broken in v. 10.4 as well which, together with the ongoing lack of support for `FullGraphics`, is really very unfortunate.

Comment: @MarcoB, it's working nicely.  Except if you set Xmax = 7.6, for example (no mesh).

Comment: @Cham Good point! I added a fix for non-integer ranges. It should work now.

Comment: @MarcoB, I think the `Floor`gives a problem when `Xmax  < 1`.

Comment: @MarcoB, yep, try Xmax = 0.6.  Error message !

Comment: @Cham See the new version. I think I may have been trying too hard before... :-)

Comment: @MarcoB, yes, it appears to be right now.  Thanks a lot !